# Is there any scrollbar component in java swing ,there by which we can select first and last rows in a JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

Is there any scrollbar component in java swing ,there by which we can select first and last rows in a JTable?

Comment: I don't see the point between JScrollbar (used in fact by the internal JScrollPane of a JTable) and automated selection of first and last row of JTable. Can you give a little more explanations ?)

Comment: Riduidel is right. Further more that a kind of behavior seems to be easily added to JTable implementation through extension.